# SpaCy permission denied

Tags: python, terminal, spacy

I sorta have two issues, and I only mention both because I think they might be related.

**Problem 1:**

I believe I have two versions of Python3 downloaded (one through Anaconda) because when I run

```
$ pip3 --version
```

I get

```
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

and when I run

```
$ pip --version
```

I get

```
pip 10.0.1 from /Users/skylerilenstine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

(I know this is probably a roundabout way of figuring this out lol).

**Problem 2:**

Something went wrong with SpaCy.

Just yesterday, when I ran

```
python3 name_of_my_program.py
```

from terminal, it worked fine. But today I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

When I run

```
which `spacy`
```

in terminal, I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/spacy: Permission denied
```

It makes sense that it's under this path, as the other one was the anaconda version, and the code was never working in anaconda. But now it's not working in terminal either. I'm not sure what "Permission denied" means or how to fix it.

Could this have happened because I downloaded a new version of python 3 through anaconda, or is it unrelated? Should I redownload SpaCy?

Answer (score -1):

## To solve problem 2 (Windows);

1. Log into Windows as an administrator.
2. Right-click on the file or folder you want to change permissions for.
3. Select "Properties."
4. Click the "Security" tab.
5. Click the "Edit" button.
6. Click the "Add" button to add a new user or group to the list.
7. Select the user that you want to change permissions for.
8. Check the boxes for the permissions you want to add for that user or
   group.

## To solve problem 2 (Mac);

1. Apply permissions to all items in a folder or a disk
2. Select a folder or a disk, then choose File > Get Info.
3. Click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter an administrator name
   and password.
4. Click the Action pop-up menu , then choose “Apply to enclosed
   items.”

---

## Problem 1;

Yes you seemingly have a "standard" python install and a anaconda install. Depending on your needs you may wish to uninstall one them. Personally I would get rid of anaconda, it is way too much. If you are new to python just stick with the basics... A text editor and a terminal!

Comment: Thank you.

I'm on a Mac tho. Also, I didn't sign-in any differently between it working and not working...

Comment: Ive edited my answer to include mac instructions for file permissions. And to be honest this is why  i reccomend the move away from anaconda, i found strange things happen like this, just install spacy in your normal python and remove anaconda.

Comment: also you can upgrade the non-anaconda pip with sudo -H pip3/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Ur gonna hate me lol, but I decided to redownload spacy to the **anaconda** one. I just like working in it. Is there a way to somehow converge the paths for this one and the other version of python that the terminal pulls from so that when I install packages both can draw from them?

Comment: Hey its your prerogative which environment you use, if you don't plan on using the standard install (non-anaconda) then you can just move all your dist-packages ( I dont know where this is on mac, on linux it's at /usr/lib/python{python-version} and /usr/local/lib/python{python-version} and /usr/lib/python3 is the shared module directory for python3. ) to you r anaconda dist-packages directory